# iOS file upload issue - iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 8 (beta) - Mobile Safari

Tags: php, ios

There seems to be a file upload issue on iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 8 (beta) on iPhones. In both cases, the file does not get uploaded with Mobile Safari.

File uploads work on desktop (Chrome/Firefox/Safari). File uploads also work on iOS 7.1.1. Interestingly the file upload works on Mobile Chrome on iOS 8 (beta)?

Link to try out mobile file upload:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html (use upload button)

```
Additional Info from Apache Server:
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client, referer: http://websitename.com/fileupload.php
```

HTML Form

```
<form name="fileUpload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="add_text" style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 52px;border-top: none;">
    <div class="add_textarea">
    <h2>CHOOSE YOUR IMAGE</h2>
    <input type="file" name="upfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="Upload" style="margin-top: 15px;" class="submit_btn" id="submitImage"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Are file uploads on Mobile Safari really not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar issue with our upload script. Did you ever find a solution to this?